# the error handling of cgi.FieldStorage

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to ask about the error handling of cgi.FieldStorage()
https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html
I have reference the exmaple to write my program
below is my program

```
arg = cgi.FieldStorage()
if "s_d" not in arg or "e_d" not in arg:
   print "no valid input"
   return 
else:
   s_date = arg["s_d"].value
   e_date = arg["e_d"].value

print s_date
print type(s_date)
print e_date
print type(e_date)
```

It works when I click below URI
http: / /hostname/test.py?s_d=%272015-01-01%27&e_d=%272015-02-01%27

When I want to try the error handling, it failed 
http: / /hostname/test.py

The error log is like below

```
File "test.py", line 152
    return 
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
Premature end of script headers: test.py
```

I want to protect my program.
Make it can go with no parameter or whatever parameters.
Please advice.
many thanks

Comment: As the error suggested, you have not defined a a python function (using `def`) so you can't really use the `return statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , thanks for @Forge 's suggestion
I write my program again, it is cool now.

```
    arg = cgi.FieldStorage()
    s_date = ''
    e_date = ''
    def get_parameter():
        global s_date,e_date
        if "s_d" not in arg or "e_d" not in arg:
           print "no valid input"
           return
        else:
           s_date = arg["s_d"].value
           e_date = arg["e_d"].value
    get_parameter()
```